# Move the Image when click on the button in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm moving the image when click on the button using the JavaScript. And i also I'm using the CSS. Please guide me how can add the JavaScript
Here is my code image .
[image]

Comment: You haven't asked a question. You haven't included code as a [mcve]. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] (this means, your _code must be in the question itself, as [formatted text](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251361/4642212) and [**not** a picture](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4642212)_), along with your _desired_ results, your _actual_ results, including all _errors_, and demonstrate _your research and your attempts_ and explain what precisely didn’t work.

Answer (score -1):

```js
    let btn = document.getElementById('moveBtn');
    let img = document.getElementById('backgroundImg');

    btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        img.style.left = "100px"
    })
```

```css
    
        #backgroundImg {
            position: relative;
            height: 100px;
            width: 100px;
            background-color: red;
        }
        
        .moveImage {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            width: 200px;
        }
```

```html
  <div class="moveImage ">
        <img src="" alt="" id="backgroundImg">
        <button id="moveBtn">Click</button>
    </div>
```

Here's the code , i've used backgroundcolor but you can use background image